# Regex pattern for image (not link)

Tags: regex

Can anyone give me the pattern of the regex to get all the local images ONLY. :(
I'm using the code below but it includes the image links.

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex("[^\\/:*?\"<>|]+\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

input:

```
 http://dl9.glitter-graphics.net/pub/846/846279rr8zhg26y6.gif
 images/strawberries.jpg
```

output:

```
 846279rr8zhg26y6.gif
 strawberries.jpg
```

**I don't want the `846279rr8zhg26y6.gif`**

Comment: what is the output that you are looking for

Comment: If images is guaranteed to be in the location you could just do something like `images\\/([^\\s.]+)\\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)

Comment: If the task is specific enough then regex searching data that happens to be html is fine.  In this case it seems the actual data is URLs however.

Answer (score 0):

If your input strings are bounded somehow (e.g. inside ""s or at the start of the input string) then things are easier, and if the input has a semantic context of being a (relative or absolute) URL, and you only want relative URLs, then easier still.

I would however note that the extension part should probably be `jpe?g` rather than just `jpg` and I do wish people would never ever use a `bmp` on a webpage!

Comment: This seems more suited to be a comment than an answer

Comment: I have this all HTML files and all I want is to filter the source of the images that is in local disk. Not the source that I can access through the internet(URL Links) because I will add cid (programmatically ) to those in the local images.